# Utility Classes in Jar Cannot find EJBs When Packaged In EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, ear

I have some core functionality used across webapps packaged in a common classes JAR. This JAR has classes that reference EJBs and a web app that references both the CORE.jar and the EJB.jar.

- CORE.jar -> EJB.jar
- WEBAPP.war -> CORE.jar
- WEBAPP.war -> EJB.jar

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 to deploy in Eclipse development plugin.

In my deploy log I see failures such as follows.
SEVERE: Class [ Lnet/webframeone/ejb/data/GeoLocationsBeanLocal; ] not found. Error while loading [ class net.webframeone.servlet.action.GetGeoLocation ]

The reference here is to a class in the EJB.jar from a class in the CORE.jar. 
The EAR has roughly has the structure as follows.

- EJB.jar
- WEBAPP.war
- lib/CORE.jar

I have tried putting classpath entry in manifest.mf on CORE.jar to no avail.

If I package the WEBAPP up with a deployment assembly that includes the CORE.jar and EJB.jar and deploy it outside of an EAR it works fine.

Any ideas would be enthusiastically excepted!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about GlassFish server. I use JBoss. I've seen this issue in below cases -

1. /META-INF/application.xml did not mention all modules properly.
2. Dependencies not specified for deployment

Comment: Please see below link http://javahowto.blogspot.sg/2009/10/sample-applicationxml-java-ee-5.html Does your /META-INF/application.xml look similar to one on this page?